# CSS drop down navigation

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigation

I'm sure this is something simple I'm missing... My drop down menu is opening within the main navigation, widening it.  Here is a link to the page I'm working on.  The issue is with the navigation below the App buttons.

http://membershq.incentiveusa.com/AwardPages/GoalUp_Test2/index_test3.html#

Here is my HTML:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="section-title2 text-center">        
                <div class="navigation">
                    <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
<ul >
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="about.html">Who We Are</a></li>
    <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
    </ul></li>
    <li><a href="HowItWorks.html">How It Works</a></li>
    <li><a href="FactsStats.html">Facts</a></li>
    <li><a href="ParentingTools.html">Tools</a></li>
    <li><a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
    <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="awards.html">Brand Name Awards</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.navigation{
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
width: 100%;
background-color: #0f9cde;
position: absolute;
display: block;
margin-bottom: 15px;
z-index: 1000;
top: 735px;
margin-left: -15px;
}
/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/
.navigation ul{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
z-index: 10000;
text-align:center;
}

/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/
.navigation li{
display:inline-block;
margin-right: 0px;
background-color:#0f9bde;

}

/*Style for menu links*/
.navigation li a {

min-width: 189px;
height: 50px;
text-align: center;
line-height: 50px;
font-family: 'Maven Pro', sans-serif;
font-size:18px;
color: #fff;
width:100%;
background-color: #0f9cde;
text-decoration: none;
display:block;

}

/*Hover state for top level links*/
.navigation li:hover a {
color: #f7a800;
text-decoration: underline;
}

/*Style for dropdown links*/
.navigation li:hover ul a {
background: #f7a800;
color: #ffffff;
height: 40px;
line-height: 40px;
z-index: 10001;
}

/*Hover state for dropdown links*/
.navigation li:hover ul a:hover {
background: #fff;
color: #f7a800;
}

/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/
.navigation li ul{
display: none;
z-index: 10001;
}

/*Make dropdown links vertical*/
.navigation li ul li {
display: block;
float: none;
}

/*Prevent text wrapping*/
.navigation li ul li a {
width: auto;
min-width: 100px;
padding: 0 20px;
}

.navigation ul li:hover ul{
display:block;
}

/*Display the dropdown on hover*/
navigation ul li a:hover  {
display: block;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a position:absolute to the selector `.navigation li ul`

```css
.navigation{
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
width: 100%;
background-color: #0f9cde;
position: absolute;
display: block;
margin-bottom: 15px;
z-index: 1000;
margin-left: -15px;
}
/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/
.navigation ul{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
z-index: 10000;
text-align:center;
}

/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/
.navigation li{
display:inline-block;
margin-right: 0px;
background-color:#0f9bde;

}

/*Style for menu links*/
.navigation li a {

min-width: 189px;
height: 50px;
text-align: center;
line-height: 50px;
font-family: 'Maven Pro', sans-serif;
font-size:18px;
color: #fff;
width:100%;
background-color: #0f9cde;
text-decoration: none;
display:block;

}

/*Hover state for top level links*/
.navigation li:hover a {
color: #f7a800;
text-decoration: underline;
}

/*Style for dropdown links*/
.navigation li:hover ul a {
background: #f7a800;
color: #ffffff;
height: 40px;  
line-height: 40px;
z-index: 10001;
}

/*Hover state for dropdown links*/
.navigation li:hover ul a:hover {
background: #fff;
color: #f7a800;
}

/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/
.navigation li ul{
display: none;
z-index: 10001;
  
  position: absolute;
}

/*Make dropdown links vertical*/
.navigation li ul li {
display: block;
float: none;
}

/*Prevent text wrapping*/
.navigation li ul li a {
width: auto;
min-width: 100px;
padding: 0 20px;
}

.navigation ul li:hover ul{
display:block;
}

/*Display the dropdown on hover*/
navigation ul li a:hover  {
display: block;

}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="section-title2 text-center">        
                <div class="navigation">
<ul >
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="about.html">Who We Are</a></li>
    <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
    </ul></li>
    <li><a href="HowItWorks.html">How It Works</a></li>
    <li><a href="FactsStats.html">Facts</a></li>
    <li><a href="ParentingTools.html">Tools</a></li>
    <li><a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
    <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="awards.html">Brand Name Awards</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
                  </div></div></div>
```

Comment: Please note that i have removed some code in order to show the snippet properly, but it should work fine on the original code as well.

Comment: I'm also having an issue with the location of the sub navigation.  It is not lining up directly below the top level on the desktop version, and it is floating to the left in the mobile version.  Any ideas?

Comment: Add `#menu ul {min-width: 100%;}` to your mobile styles and `#menu ul {min-width: 189px; /*matches parent link min-width*/}` to your desktop styles.

Comment: Also only apply the `.navigation li ul {position: absolute;}` to your desktop styles. if you do this you can disregard my earlier comment about applying `min-width:100%;` to your mobile styles.

Comment: The .navigation li ul position was already set to absolute.  The first comments worked, however in the mobile version the "drop down" menu options are hovering over the rest of the navigation making it difficult to smoothly use.  How can I have the nested navigation bump the rest of the navigation down?  Hope that makes sense!