# CSS navigation menu not nesting in mobile version

Tags: html, css

So I am playing with the positioning of my drop down menu items.  When I get them looking correctly in desktop version, they are sitting on top of the top level buttons in mobile version and not pushing them down.  When I have them correctly nesting in the mobile version, they are sitting in a blue background in desktop version.  Here is a link to my site:  http://membershq.incentiveusa.com/AwardPages/GoalUp_Test2/index_test2.html

Here is the HTML:

```
        <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="section-title2 text-center">        
                <div class="navigation">
                    <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a>
    <ul>

    <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
    </ul></li>
    <li><a href="HowItWorks.html">How It Works</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="FactsStats.html">Facts</a></li>
    <li><a href="ParentingTools.html">Tools</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>

    <li><a href="awards.html">Brand Name Awards</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

</div></div></div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.navigation{
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
width: 100%;
background-color: #0f9cde;
position: absolute;
display: block;
margin-bottom: 15px;
z-index: 1000;
top: 735px;
margin-left: -15px;
}
/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/
.navigation ul{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
z-index: 1000;
text-align:center;



}

/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/
.navigation li{
display:inline-block;
margin-right: 0px;
background-color:#0f9bde;
vertical-align: top;
}

/*Style for menu links*/
.navigation li a {

min-width: 189px;
height: 50px;
text-align: center;
line-height: 50px;
font-family: 'Maven Pro', sans-serif;
font-size:18px;
color: #fff;
width:100%;
background-color: #0f9cde;
text-decoration: none;
display:block;

}

/*Hover state for top level links*/
.navigation li:hover a {
color: #f7a800;
text-decoration: underline;
}

/*Style for dropdown links*/
.navigation li:hover ul a {
background: #f7a800;
color: #ffffff;
height: 40px;
line-height: 40px;

}

/*Hover state for dropdown links*/
.navigation li:hover ul a:hover {
background: #fff;
color: #f7a800;
}

/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/
.navigation li ul{
display: none;
position: absolute;
}

/*Make dropdown links vertical*/
.navigation li ul li {
display: block;
float: none;
}

/*Prevent text wrapping*/
.navigation li ul li a {
width: auto;
min-width: 100px;
padding: 0 20px;
}

.navigation ul li:hover ul{
display:block;
}

/*Display the dropdown on hover*/
.navigation ul li a:hover  {
display: block;

}



/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/
.show-menu {
font-family:'Maven Pro', sans-serif;
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
background: #f7a800;
text-align: center;
padding: 10px 0;
display: none;
}

/*Hide checkbox*/
input[type=checkbox]{
display: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
}

/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu{
display: block;
}

#menu ul {min-width: 189px; }

/*Responsive Styles*/

@media screen and (max-width : 975px){
/*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
.navigation ul {
    position: static;
    display: none;
}
/*Create vertical spacing*/
.navigation li {
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}
/*Make all menu links full width*/
.navigation ul li, li a {
    width: 100%;
}
.navigation li ul li {
    width: 100%;
}
#menu ul {min-width: 100%;}
/*Display 'show menu' link*/
.show-menu {
    display:block;
}
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want the drop down menu items to appear in desktop version as they are appearing now, but in the mobile version for the drop down items to nest with the top level items and drop down the items below it.... hopefully that makes sense?

Comment: The problem seems to be that you can't actually navigate to a child node in the menu since a click on the parent node triggers a page request?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS drop down navigation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30985001/css-drop-down-navigation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use a media query to alter the behaviour on mobile devices. Try this:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
   #menu ul {
       position: static;
   }
}
```

As of now the child ul is still positioned as absolute and will overlay the rest of the menu. If you set it to static it will rather "push down" the menu item siblings.